# Bonita 7.2 not supporting java 7

Tags: java, business-process-management, bonita

I am new In Bonita BPM, I am trying to learn web service connector.
I am using weather web service to test.

I have created the process diagrams, and using Get weather service. i am using Groovy Script for map data with the process variable, which I have followed from some videos, but the script was in Groovy.

So instead of Groovy Script I want to use Java. I have gone to Exceution Tab -> Clicked the Connector -> Edit -> Have Entered All the datas and clicked Next upto the point I reached Output Operations.
In here when editing using "Take Value Of" I can find Script which is containing Groovy, but I want to do Java Code on it so after clicking on java I get "Null Argument :"  and then nothing happens, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you map a connector output to a process data using "Take value of" the expression editor will let you choose which output you want to map and optionally let you do some pre-processing before actually updating the process variable.

In the expression editor, "Java" expression type will only let you use business and process variables methods. It does not provide access to connector outputs methods. So it is not really useful because you are unlikely to want to update process data with other process data in connector output operations.

If you need to process the connector outputs before mapping them to business or process variables you should define a Groovy script. Note that Groovy is really similar to Java so it should not be to difficult to achieve what you want. If you want to learn more about differences between Java and Groovy I recommend to read the [documentation page](http://www.groovy-lang.org/differences.html) that list all differences between the two language.